# Using Cloudflare SSL: Getting mixed content errors

Tags: ssl

Because my site is an eCommerce site, and because the browsers are reporting sites with any http links as not secure to the user, I signed up for the free Cloudflare SSL.  However, I got a lot of mixed content errors and had to go into all my content and blocks and change the link code to a relative location link or https.

but I still have these mixed content errors for style sheets that are getting imported or called in the Drupal or Theme code.  I cannot find where I could change these links.  Here are a few:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dm-treasures.biz/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://dm-treasures.biz/modules/system/system.base.css?oyx30a'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
>   Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dm-treasures.biz/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://dm-treasures.biz/modules/system/system.menus.css?oyx30a'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

I've tried using a couple of Drupal modules (Htaccess and SecurePages), and setting the Cloudflare "Always use HTTPS" setting, but I'm not able to fix this problem. I am using Drupal 7.x and my hosting service is BlueHost.

Given the above configuration and problem statement, what can I do to prevent my site for getting mixed content errors?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I've edited the post to ask a specific question rather than saying "Any Ideas?"  I hope this solves the "too Broad" problem.

Comment: Ideally, you should have your Drupal server setup up with an SSL cert as well.  CF can issue free Edge certificates to use with your server.   Another alternative is to use a CF page rule with the Automatic HTTPS Rewrites action.

Comment: Hi CG Monroe, and thanks for the answer.  My Drupal site is located in a sub-directory of my main hosting account (desautel.net), and dm-treasures.biz points there.  desautel.net does have a Bluehost SSL certificate, but does not seem to impact dm-treasures.biz.

Comment: My mixed content were of two types - links to images located at a higher point in the hosting account (above the Drupal location), and I fixed these by editing the links in all my content and structure in Drupal.  I cannot figure out how to fix the links that go to script and CSS files inside the Drupal installation, probably imported or referenced by my theme?

Comment: I think I have this fixed:  On CloudFlare, under the "Crypto" tab, at the bottom of the page, I found an option called "Automatic Rewrites" and turned it on.  This appears to have fixed the problem.  I do not know if this is new, but no one has every mentioned this to me, not even CloudFlare support (they mentioned the "Always Use HTTPS" option, but not this one!).